# Video not centered In any layout [Android]

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm trying to center a video played in a Fullscreen activity but whatever parameter i place in whatever layout doesn't seem to work

This is the piece of my manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".VideoActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
</activity>
```

My video_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <VideoView 
    android:id="@+id/videoView" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the activity in case you need it

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);

    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    setContentView(videoHolder);
    Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+ R.raw.video);
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(video);
    videoHolder.start();

    videoHolder.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            jump();
        }
    });
}   

private void jump() {
    if(isFinishing())
      return;
     finish();
     pd.dismiss();
    }
 }
```

I've tried with FrameLayou, RelativeLayout, LinearLayout

centering gravity, centering layout_gravity
and it keeps displaying it on top of the window in portrait and in the left-bottom corner in landscape

I'd put a photo but I lack of reputation
Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI `fill_parent` is deprecated, you should be using `match_parent` instead (unless you are targetting *really old* versions of Android).

Comment: Yes... I've tried also with match parent, neither with match fill or wrap

Comment: I didn't say it would fix your problem, just that it's deprecated and therefore poor style to use it. That's why I posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
    </VideoView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried it exactly like that before
and still not centered, landscape nor portrait

Comment: @MawBoc: Then perhaps the issue is with whatever is holding the `FrameLayout`. Use Hierarchy View to try to determine what is going on.